# Agregar restricciones con código en Swift

Tags: swift, constraints

Estoy trabajando con archivos .xib en Swift y tengo un UITableViewController con respectivas celdas, pero necesito agregar restricciones para que la última celda se posicione en la parte inferior de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las restricciones que usualmente trabajan no funcionan en un UITableView, ¿Cómo puedo agregar una restricción que me permita tener la celda "powered by" en la parte inferior(bottom=0), pegado al menú?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que no se mueva del fondo necesitarás ponerlo como una vista por fuera de tu `tableview`

Así, pones tus constraints para pegar la vista abajo, entre la tabla y el menú.